# CSS: aligning div to the top of the previous div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a div to the top of the div before it.

I've used `vertical-align:top;` but it doesn't seem to work at all and it doesn't align the div to the top.

To explain this I've created this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a5uk01c5/1/)

And this is the div I need to align to the top of the previous div:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; background:#EFEFEF; border-radius:4px; margin:5px; padding:10px;">
<p style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px;vertical-align: top;">Draw Days</p>

<label for="one">
<input type="radio" id="one" name="duration" value="1" />
Tue
</label>

<label for="two">
<input type="radio" id="two" name="duration" value="1" />
Fri
</label>

<label for="two">
<input type="radio" id="two" name="duration" value="1" />
Tue &amp; Fri
</label>
</div>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pro tip: It really really really helps to give some class names to your elements and keep the styling in a separate CSS. That makes quick changes so much easier.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I know but thanks for the "tip".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to both divs. Because they are inline blocks, they are in the text flow. `vertical-align: top` will align them with the top of the line they are on. You will also need to remove the 5px top margin of the second div to make them visually align properly.

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9pzuhnfy/1/

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `float:left` property, and you have to add another div after these divs which has `clear:both` property.

https://jsfiddle.net/a5uk01c5/2/

If you do not want to use these properties you should set your divs as inline-block. Beause Vertical-align just effects inline and inline-block properties.

Comment: Well, you don't "have to". Display as inline block should work fine if you give them the same alignment.

Comment: And extra divs for clearing considered bad practice, since you need extra elements purely to support this styling. [self clearing](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) is a better solution.